# Multicolumn list does not align vertically properly

Tags: itemize, multicol, enumitem

I have a list of 10 items each having again 10 sub items. To fit it on one single page, I use the multicol package to create 3 columns. However the 3 columns do not align properly. I the following picture, the second column is always a bit lower than the first and the last element of the second column is in the third column. I can't find my mistake. Why does it not align properly? Thanks a lot for any advice...

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 


% define page size, margin size
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}
\voffset=-2cm
\hoffset=-3cm
\textheight24cm
\textwidth15.5cm
\topmargin1cm
\oddsidemargin3.25cm
\evensidemargin3.25cm


\begin{document}

 \begin{multicols}{3}

\tiny

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0.5cm]
\item Block 1
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 1 Item1
  \item Block 1  Item 2
  \item Block 1 Item 3
  \item Block 1 Item 4
  \item Block 1  Item 5
  \item Block 1 Item 6
  \item Block 1 Item 7
  \item Block 1  Item 8
  \item Block 1 Item 9
  \item Block 1 Item 10
  \end{itemize}

\item Block 2
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 2 Item  1
\item Block 2 Item  2
\item Block 2 Item  3
\item Block 2 Item  4
\item Block 2 Item  5
\item Block 2 Item  6
\item Block 2 Item  7
\item Block 2 Item  8
\item Block 2 Item  9
\item Block 2 Item  10
  \end{itemize}

\item Block 3
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 3 Item  1
\item Block 3 Item  2
\item Block 3 Item  3
\item Block 3 Item  4
\item Block 3 Item  5
\item Block 3 Item  6
\item Block 3 Item  7
\item Block 3 Item  8
\item Block 3 Item  9
\item Block 3 Item  10
  \end{itemize}

\item Block 4
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 4 Item  1
\item Block 4 Item  2
\item Block 4 Item  3
\item Block 4 Item  4
\item Block 4 Item  5
\item Block 4 Item  6
\item Block 4 Item  7
\item Block 4 Item  8
\item Block 4 Item  9
\item Block 4 Item  10
  \end{itemize}  

 \columnbreak 

\item Block 5
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 5 Item  1
\item Block 5 Item  2
\item Block 5 Item  3
\item Block 5 Item  4
\item Block 5 Item  5
\item Block 5 Item  6
\item Block 5 Item  7
\item Block 5 Item  8
\item Block 5 Item  9
\item Block 5 Item  10
  \end{itemize}

  \item Block 6
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 6 Item  1
\item Block 6 Item  2
\item Block 6 Item  3
\item Block 6 Item  4
\item Block 6 Item  5
\item Block 6 Item  6
\item Block 6 Item  7
\item Block 6 Item  8
\item Block 6 Item  9
\item Block 6 Item  10
  \end{itemize}

\item Block 7
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 7 Item  1
\item Block 7 Item  2
\item Block 7 Item  3
\item Block 7 Item  4
\item Block 7 Item  5
\item Block 7 Item  6
\item Block 7 Item  7
\item Block 7 Item  8
\item Block 7 Item  9
\item Block 7 Item  10
\end{itemize}

\item Block 8
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 8 Item  1
\item Block 8 Item  2
\item Block 8 Item  3
\item Block 8 Item  4
\item Block 8 Item  5
\item Block 8 Item  6
\item Block 8 Item  7
\item Block 8 Item  8
\item Block 8 Item  9
\item Block 8 Item  10
\end{itemize}

\item Block 9
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 9 Item  1
\item Block 9 Item  2
\item Block 9 Item  3
\item Block 9 Item  4
\item Block 9 Item  5
\item Block 9 Item  6
\item Block 9 Item  7
\item Block 9 Item  8
\item Block 9 Item  9
\item Block 9 Item  10

  \end{itemize}
\item Block 10
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, leftmargin=0cm]
\item Block 10 Item  1
\item Block 10 Item  2
\item Block 10 Item  3
\item Block 10 Item  4
\item Block 10 Item  5
\item Block 10 Item  6
\item Block 10 Item  7
\item Block 10 Item  8
\item Block 10 Item  9
\item Block 10 Item  10
\end{itemize}  
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}


   \end{document}
```

Comment: i haven't debugged this, but have experimented.  if `\columnbreak` is inserted before block 9, the first and second columns are evened out.  presumably you added `\columnbreak` after block 4 because you wanted only full blocks in each column.  that probably forced the gaps around the block headers to be as small as possible, perhaps applying a shrink component.  that didn't happen in the unconstrained column 2, so there wasn't room for the last line of block 8.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you consider using a horizontal layout – I mean e.g.  block 2 would be to the right of block 1 and block 3 to the right of block 2, then a new line of three blocks and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are caught by the fact that LaTeX's decision to break a galley into columns and pages depends on many parameters. In your example you force a column break in the first column, simplified it means there is forcing penalty of -10000 added there (not quite but close enough for this discussion).

As this is a forcing penalty so LaTeX will take a break there. This is not quite the same as asking LaTeX to make a column of height 343.5pt (which happens to be the height of those columns). In the latter case LaTeX would have chosen an earlier break because in its eyes that would have been better (cheaper less penalties/costs compared to the costs to break at your desired place without your extra help).

In the second column, however, you have not added another column break so there LaTeX was free to choose and did what it would have done in the first column too, not to break after the block but before the last item of the previous block.

Basically the incentive to break after the block is not very high (by default -51) and the cost to break between items has the same penalty attached. If you change those penalties you will see a different behavior.

For example, already `\setlist{endpenalty=-500}` is enough to make it decide that the end of the itemize is much more attractive than breaking between items.

Alternatively, add a second `\columnbreak` before block 9. That will work too, because this is nothing else than saying this is a "really really" attrictive place to break.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your in-depth explanation. I now understand what the problem was. I don’t have that much latex experience and would never thought about that. I tried both your suggestions and both worked equally well. Now the list looks as intended. I am really thankful. Thanks a lot for your advice!